# Why no softmax in predict_labels() in DeepLabv3+?

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

In function

```
def predict_labels(images, model_options, image_pyramid=None)
```

from model.py, we have:

```
predictions[output] = tf.argmax(logits, 3)
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1c99681ed94495f446399e247a8d63e07f28391c/research/deeplab/model.py#L191

I expected something like:

```
predictions[output] = tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), 3)
```

So why no softmax there?

Comment: Because `tf.argmax` returns index and adding `tf.nn.softmax` would not change the results.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. To add more context, when doing prediction at multiple scales however, we have:

    `outputs_to_predictions[output].append(tf.expand_dims(tf.nn.softmax(logits), 4))`

[link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/1c99681ed94495f446399e247a8d63e07f28391c/research/deeplab/model.py#L142)

But in this case, since the list is reduced with mean afterward, we need to scale the logits correctly.